# Constrain parent node transform to child bounds

Tags: matrix, transformation

If I have some node rendering tree set up, where a node basically has a draw method to render things, and a transform, represented as a 3x3 matrix, with scale and translation.

Now, I would like to constrain the scale and translation of that node (constrain the transform basically) to the bounds of the child. So if the child is a 300x400 image, I want the root to only scale large enough to see the whole image, not more. So does the translation, that it does not go beyond the image bounds. How can I achieve that? Which sorcery of mathematics must I read about to learn this? Affine transforms or what?

Comment: OK, I am just guesstimating, but it seems like I am looking to "normalize" the translation by removing the scaling. Then I can check that "pure" translation against my constraint... Easier said than done, though.. How can I *reverse* the scale effect. Multiply by which inverse matrix?

Comment: This question helped me resolve my issue: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34262/transformation-matrix-that-maps-a-window?rq=1